# Wasm file cannot be cached by browser

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, webassembly

Wasm file cannot be cached by browser.

I deployed a program in nginx that contains a wasm file. In the nginx. conf file, I set cache control=public, but every time the browser is refreshed, the browser still downloads the wasm file from the server, although the response header already has cache control=public.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPinc.png)

````
location /ncsic/ {
    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /ncsic/index.html;
    if ($request_filename ~ .*\.(wasm)$) {
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
}```
````